# Issue with opening the generated file in MS Excel using axlsx_rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, axlsx

I am using `axlsx_rails` in my Rails project to generate an excel file with validations and dropdowns. After generating the File, I tried to open the file in MS Excel and it said that it needs to repair the file and all the validations and dropdowns are cleared off.

Versions

```
axlsx_rails - 0.1.5
axlsx - 1.3.6
rubyzip - 1.2.0
rails - 4.1.2
ruby - 2.2.2
```

Code

```
@excel = Axlsx::Package.new
@excel.workbook.add_worksheet(name: "Samples") do |ws|
    ws.add_row @field_names
    sheet.add_data_validation("G2:G1000", {
       :type => :list,
       :formula1 => '"Jim", "Tom", "Jack"',
       :showDropDown => false,
       :showErrorMessage => true,
       :errorTitle => '',
       :error => 'Please use the dropdown selector to choose the value',
       :errorStyle => :stop,
       :showInputMessage => true,
       :prompt => 'Choose the value from the dropdown'})
    end
    @excel.serialize "tmp/SampleTemplate.xlsx"
```

Sending the file using

`send_file "tmp/SampleTemplate.xlsx"`

The generated file is working in LibreOffice but not in MSExcel

Please help

Comment: can you try generating without validations and see if you are able to open the file? pS: tag me when you reply

Comment: @kiddorails Yes. I can able to open the file without validations. But I need the validations for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The issue is in the line,

```
:formula_1 => '"Jim", "Tom","Jack"'
```

I've changed it to,

```
:formula_1 => '"Jim, Tom, Jack"'
```